# Resize widget after contents are added to it

Tags: python, pyside2

I have a `QComboBox` that starts blank when the user start the program. Later, contents are added to the widget including an icon for each index. If I add the contents before the program starts, the icons and size of the `QComboBox` are perfect. But if it is added after the program has already initialized then the icon is cropped and the size is not perfect.

```py
from PySide2 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore


class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(self.__class__, self).__init__()
        self.setMinimumSize(500,400)
        self.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

        self.addNow = False

        self.combo = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
        self.btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Add Items')

        self.combo.setStyleSheet('font-size: 20px')

        self.layout.addWidget(self.combo)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.btn)

        self.items = ['hi', 'hello', 'goodbye', 'nice day', 'bonjour']
        self.icon = QtGui.QPixmap('checker.png')
        self.combo.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(40,40))

        if self.addNow:
            self.addItems()
            self.btn.setDisabled(True)

        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.addItems)


    def addItems(self):

        for item in self.items:
            self.combo.addItem(self.icon, item)


import sys
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
mywin = MyWindow()
mywin.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I've tried several `sizePolicy` but neither are able to resize the icon.

Here is a photo example, I can hard-code the size of the QComboBox, but ideally I would want QT to resize it once contents are added.
[image]

Comment: Is that your real code? It seems to me that not since QLayout cannot be used directly since it has abstract methods for what you should use: QVBoxLayout or QHBoxLayout. Another mistake is that you have a type: change `QPusButton` to `QPushButton`. With these changes should work correctly, you could place an image of the problem you get since it may be a bug.

Comment: Sorry about that, this was just a  heavily simplified code written in SO. Assume the corrections you pointed out are already in the actual program.

Comment: If you want help then make sure that the question you publish is the best you can ask, I have tested it and I have not toned any problems so I assume that the code you provide is not an [MRE], so you have to do 2 things: 1) provide an MRE and 2) show an image that illustrates the problem and that corresponds to the MRE

Comment: I have just updated with a photo example.

Comment: Are they the same image? if they are not then do they have the same size?

Comment: Yup same image. Only difference is the ```QAbstractItemView``` seems to be displaying it in the correct size unlike the ```QComboBox```

Comment: 1) Okay, I think I understood you, you want the selected item (The first item "Being Good") not to have the edges, and that it behaves the same as the popup items. I am right? 2) Are you using any Qt Style Sheet or some style customization? If so, could you provide the MRE that I have asked you from the beginning, it seems that I am begging you for the MRE.

Comment: I have update the code to an MRE. If you set self.addNow to True, you will see the correct pixmap size. Set it to false then Add button and it will be cropped. Assuming you're using a perfectly square image.

Comment: I observe the same, maybe it's the style of your environment, are you using maya, nuke or similar?

Comment: Using PyCharm & Windows. I found 2 different solutions but both are a bit hacky for my liking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 ways I can overcome the problem but they're not ideal.

1. Recall `self.combo.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(40,40))` after the new items are added. This results in the widget expanding without "pushing" other widgets in the same layout out of the way.

OR

2. Set the font size of the `QComboBox` to be the same as the size of the pix map. Add the items, then reset the stylesheet. Very hacky.

```py
self.combo.setStyleSheet('font-size: 40px')
self.addItems()
self.combo.setStyleSheet('font-size: 20px')
```